# Tkinter Ttk Python: limiting text entry widget values to numbers and limiting amount of characters

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, ttk

Probably an easy one here: in tkinter, ttk, how do you limit the amount of characters that can be input by the user into an entry field? For example, only allowing the user to insert one character and limiting the ability to insert any others?

Additionally, how would I then make it so that only an intiger can be input into said text entry field, so that it doesn't allow the user to input any characters that aren't {0:9}?

Thanks :) Btw i'm fairly new to programming so the simpler put, the better :)

If it's any help to showing what to do, here's my program so far:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def calculate(*args):
    try:
        valuex=int(x.get())
        valuey=int(y.get())
        valuez=int(z.get())
        cappf.set(int(str(valuex)+str(valuey))*10**valuez)
        capnf.set(int(str(valuex)+str(valuey))*10**valuez*10**-3)
        capuf.set(int(str(valuex)+str(valuey))*10**valuez*10**-6)
    except ValueError:
        pass

root=Tk()
root.title('Capacitor Calculator')

mainframe=ttk.Frame(root, padding='10 10 10 10')
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

x=StringVar()
x_entry=ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=3, textvariable=x)
x_entry.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=(W,E))
y=StringVar()
y_entry=ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=3, textvariable=y)
y_entry.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=(W,E))
z=StringVar()
z_entry=ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=3, textvariable=z)
z_entry.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=(W,E))

cappf=StringVar()
capnf=StringVar()
capuf=StringVar()

ttk.Button(mainframe, width=7, text='Calculate', command=calculate).grid(column=2, row=5, sticky=(N, E, S, W))
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=cappf).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=N)
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=capnf).grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=N)
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=capuf).grid(column=2, row=4, sticky=N)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text='Input:').grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=N)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text='Amount:').grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=N)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text='Units:').grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=N)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text='pf').grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=N)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text='nf').grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=N)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text='uf').grid(column=3, row=4, sticky=N)
ttk.Button(mainframe, width=7, text='Quit', style='red.TButton', command=root.destroy).grid(column=2, row=6, sticky=(N, E, S, W))
ttk.Style().configure('red.TButton', foreground='red', padding=6, font='Corbel 18')
ttk.Style().configure('TLabel', padding=6, font='Corbel 16', foreground='#0077AF')
ttk.Style().configure("TButton", padding=6, relief="flat", font='Corbel 18', foreground='#00AA11')

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=3)
x_entry.focus()
y_entry.focus()
z_entry.focus()

root.bind('<Return>', calculate)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

The entry widget supports a validation callback, specified by setting the validation mode (via the `validate` property) and providing the callback itself (via the `validatecommand` property). The Tkinter documentation for how to use it is very poor, unfortunately.

The validation mode can be the strings `focusOut` (to apply the validation when the focus leaves the widget) and `key` (to apply it when the user presses a key). And `focus` and `focusIn` but I've not found them to be so useful.

The validation callback should return a boolean that states whether the current (== new, in the case of `key` validation) contents are valid. If the validation fails, the change is rejected (the contents are reset) and the invalid contents callback is invoked (via the `invalidcommand` property) which can do things like sound the bell or make the screen flash.

---

A more elaborate validation mechanism is to always *officially* claim that the edit is valid, but to change the background of the entry (or use some other indicator) to show that the edit *will be rejected*. Then, only do full validation/rejection on overall submission of the form (you were going to do that anyway, yes?). Like that, temporarily invalid states are permitted so long as the user goes back and fixes them before finishing their session. This is quite a lot more usable.

Comment: Thank you... but as said, 'i'm fairly new to programming so the simpler put, the better'... thank you anyway i'll try to get my head around that!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [spinbox](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_spinbox.htm) to enter only the integers and specify the range of values. For example, the spinbox specified in the below example will restrict the user to choose value only the range 0-9

```
from Tkinter import *
master = Tk()
w = Spinbox(master, from_=0, to=9)
w.pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: This should be a comment & not a Answer

Comment: @shaktimaan Not really; it's a _poor_ answer that has not much more than a link and no example.